# range getClientRects(), getBoundingClientRect() wrong when empty anchor is in HTML paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, range, getclientrect, getboundingclientrect

I found a possibly weird behaviour of `getClientRects() [getBoundingClientRect()]`:

Look at this HTML code:

```
<p>Text here... word1<a id='id' class='class'/>word2 Other multiline Text here...</p>
```

[Note that the a element has no text inside, I tested just this kind of code, don't know if other arrangements give the same 'bug'.]

Let's say that when user selects a range in the p 'estate' that has the anchor inside, like "word1 word2", a JS function stores start/end elements and offsets.
Next time another function creates a range with those bounds. 
But if `getClientRects()` is called on that range it yields many rects other than the two expected: first and last rects of the array indeed are the expected ones, but, between them, there are many rects that in fact cover the entire p element. 
[`range.getBoundingClientRect()` is affected too.]
How to avoid this?

Comment: some browsers will consider the `<a>` tag as an open one and close it for you over the rest of the `<p>` element. change it to `<a id='id' class='class'></a>`.

Comment: @Gil Can it happen just with a's, or with other tags too?

Comment: With some others as well, but I've never had to check this thoroughly for other elements, and it also depends on the browser's type/version. Anyway, adding a closing tag won't overcrowd your code and will assure a compatibility with all browsers.

Comment: What is the reason for the `<a>` element? Are you confusing the anchor of the user selection (i.e. the starting point for the selection) with  the `<a>` (aka "anchor") element?